# Issue remoting into a device and doing a simple ping test with Ansible

Tags: automation, ansible, cisco

After following instructions both online and in a couple of books, I am unsure of why this is happening. I have a feeling there is a missing setting, but here is the setup:

I am attempting to use the command:

```
ansible all -u $USER -m ping  -vvvv
```

Obviously using the -vvvv for debugging, but not much output aside from the fact it says it's attempting to connect. I get the following error:

```
S4 | FAILED => FAILED: Authentication failed.
```

S4 stands for switch 4, a Cisco switch I am attempting to automate configuration and show commands on. I know 100% the password I set in the host_vars file is correct, as it works when I use it from a standard SSH client.

Here are my non-default config settings in the ansible.cfg file:

```
[defaults]
transport=paramiko
hostfile = ./myhosts
host_key_checking=False
timeout = 5
```

My myhosts file:

```
[cisco-switches]
S4
```

And my host_vars file for S4:

```
ansible_ssh_host: 192.168.1.12
ansible_ssh_pass: password
```

My current version is 1.9.1, running on a Centos VM. I do have an ACL applied on the management interface of the switch, but it allows remote connections from this particular IP.

Please advise.

Comment: Can you run the command with `-vvv` to get some verbosity to the error?

Comment: The output is identical to the -vvvv option I specify above, but here it is:

`<192.168.1.11> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: username on PORT 22 TO 192.168.1.11
S4 | FAILED => FAILED: Authentication failed.`

Comment: Then it's just what it says, you can't SSH over port 22 from that machine to that switch using that username and password combination.

Comment: The thing is though when I use the ssh username@192.168.1.11 command on standard bash, I have no problem getting to my device. So obviously I am able to get to it. I have a feeling it has something to do with the rsa key settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using ansible to automate commands in a Cisco switch, I guess you want to perform the SSH connection to the switch without been prompted for password or been requested to press [Y/N] to confirm the connection.

To do that I recommend to configure the Cisco IOS SSH Server on the switch to perform RSA-Based user authentication.

First of all you need to generate RSA key pair on your Linux box:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 1024
```

Note: You can use 2048 instead 1024 but consider that some IOS versions will accept maximum 254 characters for ssh public key.

At switch side:

```
conf t    
ip ssh pubkey-chain
     username test
          key-string
               Copy the entire public key as appears in the cat id_rsa.pub
               including the ssh-rsa and username@hostname.
               Please note that some IOS versions will accept 
               maximum 254 characters.
               You can paste multiple lines.     
          exit
     exit
```

If you need that 'test' user can execute privileged IOS commands:

```
username test privilege 15 secret _TEXT_CLEAR_PASSWORD_
```

Then, test your connection from your Linux box in order to add the switch to known_hosts file. This will only happen one time for each switch/host not found in the known_hosts file:

```
ssh test@10.0.0.1
The authenticity of host '10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:d6:4b:d1:67.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '10.0.0.1' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.

ciscoswitch#
ciscoswitch#exit
```

Finally test the connection using ansible over SSH and raw module, for example:

```
ansible inventory -m raw -a "show env all" -u test
```

I hope you find it useful.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks!